# What properties of relations does this satisfy?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Define the relation $M(A, B) :\ A \cap B = \varnothing$, where the domains for $A$ and $B$ are all subsets of $\mathbb Z$. Which properties does the relation $M$ satisfy?

Comment: [Which properties exactly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Relations_over_a_set) do you want to consider and what have you tried?

Comment: It is symmetric, not reflexive, not transitive.

Comment: I want to consider the relation M(A,B)  where A,B are all subsets of the integers. I believe the relation is irreflexive because if elements were related, the intersection would not be the empty set. I think this is the only property that is satisfied of the 5 basic ones (transitive, irreflexive, reflexive, symmetric and antisymmetric).

Comment: $A\cap B = B\cap A$ so symmetry must be preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of these 5 there is indeed only one satisfied, but not the irreflexive property: it's the symmetric one.

We have $A \cap A = \varnothing$ iff $A=\varnothing$, which means that $M$ is **neither reflexive** (take $A=\mathbb Z$) **nor irreflexive** (take $A=\varnothing$).

It is **not transitive**: take $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{2\}$ and $C=\{1\}$.

It is **symmetric**, since $B\cap A=A\cap B=\varnothing$ (assuming $A\cap B=\varnothing$).

It is **not antisymmetric**: take $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$.